# Problems with BorderLayout() in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I've tried a lot of different ways, but I will explain two and what was happening (no error messages or anything, just not showing up like they should or just not showing up at all):

First, I created a JPanel called layout and set it as a BorderLayout. Here is a snippet of how I made it look:

```
JPanel layout = new JPanel();
layout.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

colorChoice = new JLabel("Choose your color: ");
layout.add(colorChoice, BorderLayout.NORTH);

colorBox = new JComboBox(fireworkColors);
colorBox.addActionListener(this);
layout.add(colorBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

In this scenario what happens is they don't show up at all. It just continues on with whatever else I added.

So then I just tried setLayout(new BorderLayout()); Here is a snippet of that code:

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    colorChoice = new JLabel("Choose your color: ");
    add(colorChoice, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    colorBox = new JComboBox(fireworkColors);
    colorBox.addActionListener(this);
    add(colorBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

In this scenario they are added, however, the width takes up the entire width of the frame and the textfield (not shown in the snippet) takes up basically everything else.

Here is what I have tried:
setPreferredSize() & setSize()

Is there something else that I am missing? Thank you.

I also should note that this is a separate class and there is no main in this class. I only say this because I've extended JPanel instead of JFrame. I've seen some people extend JFrame and use JFrame, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You created a JPanel, but didn't add it to any container.  It won't be visible until it is added to something (a JFrame, or another panel that is in a frame somewhere up the hierarhcy)
- You added two components to the same position in the BorderLayout. The last one added is the one that will occupy that position.

---

*Update:*

You do not need to extend `JFrame`.  I never do, instead I always extend `JPanel`. This makes my custom components more flexible: they can be added in another panel, or they can be added to a frame.

So, to demonstrate the problem I will make an entire, small, program:

```
public class BadGui
    {
    public static void main(String[] argv)
        {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(new JLabel("World"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

In this program I created a panel, but did not add it to anything so it never becomes visible.

In the next program I will fix it by adding the panel to the frame.

```
public class FixedGui
    {
    public static void main(String[] argv)
        {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(new JLabel("World"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Note that in both of these, when I added something to the panel, I chose different layout parameters (one label I put in 'North' and the other in 'South').

Comment: I understand the second part, but I do have a question about that. However, I am not fully processing your first point. I have a main class that I've extended JFrame to. Will I instead have to extend JFrame to this current class? If so, how do I extend both JPanel & JFrame to this one class?

Comment: My second question is if it's possible to have two components in the "North" or if you're literally only allowed to have one component per section? If that's the case, I probably shouldn't do the BorderLayout for this project.

Comment: @Tyler, If you would like 2 components to occupy the "North" instead of adding the label and combobox directly, add a panel to the North, then add the components to that panel with a layout such as the [flowlayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Comment: @Jonah Good tip! Thanks. Could you give me an example of the syntax?

Comment: @Tyler, Absolutely! Let me whip up a answer real quick.

Comment: Thanks for the help @dsh. What does the getContentPane do? If I don't put:

add(canvas) then nothing seems to show up. I am wondering if I messed it up.

Comment: Documentation: [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).  The frame's content pane is what contains all of the components in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a `JPanel` with a BorderLayout that adds a `JPanel` with a button and label to the "North"

```
public class Frames extends JFrame
{
    public Frames()
    {
        JPanel homePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel northContainerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton yourBtn = new JButton("I Do Nothing");
        JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel("I Say Stuff");

        homePanel.add(northContainerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        northContainerPanel.add(yourBtn);
        northContainerPanel.add(yourLabel);

        add(homePanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Cool Stuff");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Frames::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

**The below suggestion is assuming that your extending `JFrame`.**

## Testing

First of all, without seeing ***everything***, theres always a numerous amount of things you can try.

First off, after you load everything, try adding this in (Again, **assuming your extending** `JFrame`:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

I add this into my own Swing projects all the time, as it refreshes and checks to see that everything is on the frame.

If that doesn't work, make sure that all your `JComponent`'s are added to your `JPanel`, and ONLY your `JPanel` is on your `JFrame`. Your `JFrame` cannot sort everything out; the `JPanel` does that.

```
JPanel window = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Press me");    

add(window);
window.add(button); // Notice how it's the JPanel that holds my components.
```

One thing though, you still add your `JMenu`'s and what-not through your `JFrame`, not your `JPanel`.

Comment: **PS: Will not steal from the other answer, as it also contains a valid suggestion, try fixing your coordination for your `BorderLayout`.**

Comment: FYI: `validate` is actually not a solution, unless the container has already been `invalidate`, which doesn't normally happen when adding/removing components.  Instead you should be using `revalidate`, but you'd better have a good reason for doing so ;)

Comment: I know what it's for, but I don't actually know why I use it, but for some stupid reason when I use Java 1.6, everytime I use `repaint()` on my Mac, nothing happens. Use both, it works... 0_0

Comment: The usual pattern is to call `invaldiate`, `validate` and `repaint`.  The first marks the container hierarchy as been "invalid" and requiring layout, the second "validates" the container hierarchy by calling each container's layout manager and laying out the components and the third, obviously, schedules a repaint for the effected components.  The short hand is to call `revalidate` followed by `repaint`. `revaldiate` calls `invalidate` and `validate` itself, one less line of code which you need to type :P

Comment: My point about "having a good reason" to call it, is using `revalidate` could be bandaiding some other issue ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I swear your changing the way I code in general... ;) Editing it now.

Comment: On wards and upwards ;)